# C++ return float

Tags: c++, memory

I create a API for a Game.

My Problem: I want to read a float value from the Memory.

Result (Cheat Engine) 100

My Result with the API: 0.00000

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) float samp_health()
{
    hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, L"MyGame");
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);
    HANDLE phandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, false, pid);
    float value = 0;
    ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (float*)(PlayerPointer + HealthOffset), &value, 4, NULL);
    CloseHandle(phandle);
    return value;
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: I don't see any error checking.

Comment: I check it with Autohotkey. hp := DllCall(A_ScriptDir . "\Library.dll\samp_health",Float)
MsgBox, %hp%

Comment: And how do you know that all of those Winapi calls succeeded?

Comment: Yes, when I return 5, I get 5 back.

Comment: But that doesn't tell you anything about whether the *winapi* calls succeeded. That just tells you that you were able to call your DLL function. The `ReadProcessMemory` call could fail and you wouldn't have a clue.

Answer (score 3):

With this line,

```
HANDLE phandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, false, pid);
```

you need to check for failure.

And in this following line,

```
ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (float*)(PlayerPointer + HealthOffset), &value, 4, NULL);
```

assuming the `ReadProcessMemory` works as roughly indicated by the arguments, the `PlayerPointer` needs to be a valid pointer in the process identified by `phandle`, and if the `HealthOffset` is an offset in bytes, then `PlayerPointer` needs to be a pointer to byte.

Most likely it's not.

---

Reading process memory is generally not a good way to communicate between processes.

Here are some alternatives:

- Don't do process communication, do threads or whatever.
- Use Windows COM technology.
- Use Windows mailslots.
- Use Windows window messages (e.g. `WM_DATA`).
- Use sockets.
- Use files.
- Use pipes.

Almost anything, just not the direct access of process memory.

---

Summing up, the main problem is use of a too low level of abstraction.